# pgmmvar: One-step estimation: [======>--] Iteration 1188 of 1438 Error in rbind(t(as.matrix(Set_Vars_i[Set_Vars_i[, 2] == periods[lags + :

Tags: r, panel-data

I am trying to implement a panel vector autoregressive analysis with the package `panelvar` by Sigmund and Ferstl but I it keeps on stopping after some iterations, reporting the abovementioned error. The same code works on another dataset. Anyone can help with that?

```
rm(list=ls()) 
library(ggplot2) 
library(readxl) 
x <- read_excel(file.choose("BelowMEDIAN"))

library(plm) 
library(panelvar) 
library(devtools) 
x <- pdata.frame(x, index = "Index") 
memory.limit(size = 10000000)

panel_VAR <- (pvargmm(data = x, dependent_vars = ("PriceinEurocurrency"), predet_vars = ("LEVERAGE"), lags = 2,steps = "twostep", transformation = "fd", max_instr_dependent_vars = 3, max_instr_predet_vars = 3, collapse = TRUE, progressbar = TRUE, panel_identifier = c("Index","Date")))
```